# How to fill up memory with aim of freeing it later?

Tags: objective-c, memory

Now this might sound like a strange question, but I'm having interesting problems with IOS 5. We are scrolling large-ish textures, and everything works really well on devices (even my old 3GS with 16GB) with IOS 4.3, whereas on devices with the higher OS, we get significant stuttering, even the latest & greatest such as the iPhone 4S with 64GB. We think that perhaps it is to do with the higher priority given to multi-tasking, and maybe resources aren't being freed as much, but it's difficult to know.

What I'd like to do is (on app launch) to fill up the memory & trigger a memory warning, so the system cleans out more stuff, then free the memory I've filled (I obviously don't intend to leave this in a final app...). Perhaps this will show me whether our suspicions are well founded or not.

So far, the code I have to fill the memory is this -

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application {

    memoryFilled = NO;

    [self useUpMemory];

}

- (void) useUpMemory {

    if (memoryFilled) return;

    NSData *dummyData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:malloc(1024 * 1024) length:1024 * 1024];
    [dummyArray addObject:dummyData];
    [dummyData release];

    printf_console("Filling memory\n");

    [self performSelector:@selector(useUpMemory) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.05];

}

- (void) applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication*)application {

    memoryFilled = YES;
    [dummyArray release];

    printf_console("WARNING -> applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning()\n");

}
```

But, for some reason, the memory never fills up & the warning is never triggered. Is there a way to fill up the memory where I can free it later?

Any help much appreciated (please don't tell me I shouldn't be doing this - as I said, it's just a test!)

Comment: Just remember that `-initWithBytes:length:` copies the information you put in, meaning you are wasting over 1 million bytes with a malloc that does nothing. I would suggest using `NSMutableData's` `initWithLength:` method instead.

Comment: How many times does "Filling memory" appear in the log?

Comment: Hasn't stopped yet... (see Benedict Cohen's solution below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect this is because the memory pages are only allocated once they are written to. You could write something to force the memory pages to be allocated:

```
//interface
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *belly;

//implementation
@sythesize belly = _belly;


-(void)startEatingMemory
{
    self.belly = [NSMutableArray array];    
    [self eatMemory];
}



-(void)stopEatingMemory
{
    //TODO: Add code to log the amount of memory held in self.belly 
    self.belly = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self.belly removeAllObjects];
    [[self class] cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(eatMemory) object:nil];
}


-(void)eatMemory
{
    unsigned long dinnerLength = 1024 * 1024;
    char *dinner = malloc(sizeof(char) * dinnerLength);
    for (int i=0; i < dinnerLength; i++)
    {
        //write to each byte ensure that the memory pages are actually allocated
        dinner[i] = '!';
    }
    NSData *plate = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:dinner length:dinnerLength freeWhenDone:YES];
    [self.belly addObject:plate];

    //repeat after 2 seconds
    [self performSelector:_cmd withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
}


-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    [self stopEatingMemory];
}
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track here, as I can trigger the memory warning now, but only if I allow the memory usage to build up via leaks, ie, if I don't free up the greedyBuffer after I add it to an array with each call to useUpMemory. Do you know of any way I can build up the memory used this way, with an ultimate aim of freeing it all later? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks very much! Your new version seems to have sorted it. Now to find out if it impacts on the troublesome devices. I don't suppose you know a faster way to fill the "dinner" by the way? No probs if not.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `dummyArray` is `nil` in `useUpMemory`. This will cause the `NSData` to be immediately released.